# .NET Core console application is not creating an EXE file

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to publish a .NET Core console application following [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/10/11/net-core-how-to-publish-a-self-contained-application-exe/), but when I publish, I don't get an executable file in the PublishOutput folder (I get a DLL file).  I've also read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd).

My project file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

It seems pretty easy and straightforward, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which build tool are you using?

Comment: @AndrewHunter Just running "Publish" from Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is a weird one. I am still trying to work through it. I did find there seems to be a delay in getting the functionality from the CLI to Visual Studio 2017: [This Stack Overflow article talks about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43728542/visual-studio-2017-asp-net-publish-self-contained-dot-net-core-app).

Also, there is ongoing confusion around exactly what Output type means since it is not what we all think. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/6237) talks about it.

Comment: I've also tried doing this in VSCode with the same results. I literally do dotnet new console, dotnet restore, dotnet publish (after I make the changes to the project file adding the "RuntimeIdentifiers" section) using the parameters listed by @Brian. I still don't get an .exe. Reading through the Github issue now. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.1

Comment: I was running 15.1 and running into what you were seeing. I am updating VS now and will try again. You may want to do the same but I will let you know what I come up with.

Comment: Updating now. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Yep, that seemed to work for me as well. In addition, I also found this [example doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs) which lays out the steps.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this on the *Hello, World!* template that Visual Studio provides. Change your .csproj file to the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>-->
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I don't think the `OutputType` matters more than the `RuntimeIdentifiers` property.

Then using the console, run `dotnet restore` followed by `dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64`

This should generate an EXE file under `\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\win10-x64\publish`

View [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2017/03/19/net-core-1-1-how-to-publish-a-self-contained-application/) from the same person in your first link.

Comment: I tried this, but I'm still not getting an .exe file.

Comment: Strange, I get the executable with this method. Can you check if you have available updates for VS, under Tools > Extensions and Updates